# Hide full url from user

Tags: .htaccess

I am not sure if this is possible, but thought I'd ask. I would like to hide anything other than the base url from the user. Is there a sound way of doing this so that the user cannot view the full url with simple view source etc. For example:

```
I would like www.website.com/example to show as www.website.com
```

I will use

```
header('Location:www.website.com/example')
```

to get to my destination. Essentially, I would like to not reveal the paths so that the user can't have direct access to certain applications but has to go through membership portal, etc. Is there a guaranteed way to mask my urls as long as I don't include them in a href etc.

The other option I would like to consider is make

```
http://www.website.com/example
```

show to the user as

```
http://www.website.com/ASB#TBSD some random string
```

where the content is revealed but the user cannot access content by simply inputting

```
http://www.website.com/ASB#TBSD
```

Comment: use Domain name Masking, if you don't know, ask your hosting support, its easy. it Prevents the forwarded domain name URL from displaying in the browser's address bar, and lets you enter Meta Tags for search engine crawlers in the following fields:

Comment: Dear @SamKingston i have added it as answer. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Domain name Masking, if you don't know, ask your hosting support, its easy. it Prevents the forwarded domain name URL from displaying in the browser's address bar, and also lets you enter Meta Tags for search engine crawlers.